# All record is succussfully updating into database related to user but image is not updating into database & local folder using Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to update image into database & local folder but it's not updating related to the user, how can I do that?

**return $request**

```
    {
        _token: "8CrxYrMtEZR1UO6VDLVByLAqFkC2OuVcwws1pVX4",
        first_name: "faizan",
        last_name: "Ahmed",
        phone: "03322858593",
        company_name: "yourstitchart.com",
        Country: "GB",
        image: "iconfinder_BW_Facebook_glyph_svg_5305154.png"
    }
```

**controller**

```
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $first_name = $request->first_name;
        $last_name = $request->last_name;
        $company_name = $request->company_name;
        $phone = $request->phone;
        $Country = $request->Country;

        $user = Auth::user()->id;
        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $image = $request->file('image');
            $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Storage::disk('yourstitchart')->put($image->getFilename() . '.' . $extension, File::get($image));
            $content = new User();
            $content->image = $image->getFilename() . '.' . $extension;
            $check = User::where('id', $user)->update([
                'first_name' => $first_name,
                'last_name' => $last_name,
                'company_name' => $company_name,
                'phone' => $phone,
                'image' => $content->image
            ]);
        } else {
            $check = User::where('id', $user)->update([
                'first_name' => $first_name,
                'last_name' => $last_name,
                'company_name' => $company_name,
                'phone' => $phone
            ]);
        }
        return back()->withSuccess('Profile Updated !', $check);
    }
```

Comment: what is your variable `$content` ?

Comment: please again check my controller code i updated    $content = new User();

Comment: `if($request->hasFile('image'))` will always return false, this is not a file, it is a `string`

Comment: does your html form tag include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` ? becuase your image is a string not a file.